# Why not construct UI based on DB schema?

Tags: database, user-interface, schema

People seem to avoid building user interfaces that pull their information (names, field types, etc. as well as relationships) from a database; they instead hard-code forms (and tables, etc.) that have pretty much the same data names and types and things.

Am I making sense?

For instance, imagine an emumerated field in MySQL: why not just have the UI construct a drop-down list whenever it encounters an ENUM?  Why put the same values in both the database and the code?

Perhaps I'm just missing something; perhaps there are projects out there that do this — sort of super-crud interfaces that can be pointed at any database and from it build a fully-functional relationally-aware user interface.  Are there?

I'm possibly not quite conforming to the stackoverflow norms with this question; I shall summarise:

1. Can you please tell me of a project that constructs its user interface (solely) from analysis of the database schema?
2. Why is this not a common way to do it — surely it is good to only define data structure in one place (i.e. the database)?

Thank you, and may joyous code-love rain upon your IDE.

Comment: Isn't this the key thing Rails does for you?

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to point out that, last time I checked, .NET and Qt (and probably other environments) make it possible to use "database-aware widgets" (sometimes shortened to just data-aware widgets), which is probably the best pragmatic solution available. What I mean by data-aware widgets is that the widgets themselves know that they're linked directly to database fields, so you would have a combobox that knows that it's backed by an enum and fetches the possible values directly from the database at runtime, just like you suggested.

This is a really neat utility, and used well, it probably won't hurt anything. It still requires that you spend some time laying out widgets manually on a form, but then if you update the database to add a new value to that enum, you don't have to rebuild your app to see it show up in the UI.

But the reason most usability experts will cringe when they hear your question is because programmers tend to think that, well, why not just generate the *entire* UI, form layout and everything, from the database? And this is where it starts to get really nasty, really fast.

Let's say you have a simple Person table, with first_name, last_name, email_address, street_address, city, state, zip, and phone_number. You want to automatically generate a UI based on these fields. How do you sort the fields? I mean, ideally, first name and last name should be right next to one another. And it would look very silly if you had city and state before street address. So you have to add a new column to the table to specify sort order, if you go with the quickest method, or a new table to specify each field's order index to their field ID.

What if you want to group parts of the information separately? Then you have to add more UI-specific cruft into your database layout (to do this generically, you'll need a new table specifying which UI fields belong to which UI groupboxes). So you've only solved two problems and already your database layout has gotten twice as ugly, plus now instead of a simple O(1) layout operation when you load the UI, you've gotta do several database queries to find out what fields exist and dynamically lay them out while applying the correct widget order... and we haven't even dealt with sizing (should every field be the maximum size to fit its possible contents, or should all text fields be the same width? Wouldn't it be nice if you could say that some text fields should be one width and height, and some should be another combination? etc), or text justification, or formatting, or any other really common elementary usability requirements that will require further sacrifices from the clarity and simplicity of your database schema.

Answer (score 4):

Yup, this route has already been traveled.

Simply pointing at a database will create an oversimplified UI, not giving much more than the CRUD of an Access UI.  That's why Naked Objects (I'm one of its committers) builds its metamodel from a pojo domain model.  This allows the UI to expose any public methods as menus ... we call this "behaviourally complete".

Per the comment about the UI not being suitable for end-users, I have two points:

1. distinguish between power users vs casual users.  Most internal apps are for the former (we use Alan Coopers' term of a "sovereign application" for this), who understand the domain and don't want fancy UI stuff getting in the way.  Most external apps, eg public web sites, are for the latter.
2. for the latter, there's nothing to prevent the autogenerated UI of a tool like Naked Objects being replaced with a custom or semi-customized viewer.  One such viewer is Scimpi, I'm also working on an Eclipse RCP viewer that'll expose extension points.  But even here, the auto gen UI is still very valuable for the development team and business analysts for exploration and prototyping.

Hope some of the above has piqued your interest.  If you want more, google around, or you might want to check out my book on domain-driven design and NO, at pragprag.com.

HTH
Dan

Comment: The .NET version, still called Naked Objects, has been moved onto GitHub.
https://github.com/NakedObjectsGroup/NakedObjectsFramework


The Java version has been fully incorporated into the Apache Isis framework.
Called Apache Causeway now https://causeway.apache.org/

Answer (score 3):

1. Most visual database editors. [phpMyAdmin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/) for instance.
2. Because the database structure isn't always a very good logical structure for a user to be using, especially in the case of databases that have been denormalised on purpose for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 2):

List of projects that implement this idea.

**.NET**

- [dotObjects](http://www.codeplex.com/dotObjects)
- [Naked Objects](http://www.nakedobjects.net/)
- [TrueView](http://www.evolving-software.co.uk/index.html)

**Java**

- [Domain Object Explorer](https://doe.dev.java.net/)
- [JMatter](http://www.jmatter.org/)
- [Naked Objects](http://www.nakedobjects.org/home/no_for_java_intro.shtml)
- [Sanssouci](http://freshmeat.net/projects/sanssouci)
- [Trails](http://www.trailsframework.org/)
- [Lablz](http://lablz.com/)

**C++**

- [Typical Objects](http://tocxx.110mb.com/)

Comment: Naked Objects for Java moved into ASF, it is now Apache Isis.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically to your second question:  Alot of it really depends on your data model.  Some are very complicated and would lead to un-intuitive user interfaces.  Perhaps for simply CRUD based systems, having your UI be a front end to the database would be preferable.  In that case, I think that some of these tools would be great.  However, for some more complicated systems where some db data needs to be hidden from the users, it would be better if you UI didn't mirror the db schema.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Access has used this model for years - the database and UI development are very closely tied. You can auto-generate a form directly from a table definition with smart defaults and search built in. The model works well for developing applications with few concurrent users such as custom applications for small businesses where the amount of data stored is small.

If you are scaling to larger relational DBs with a number of concurrent users, or large databases then reliability and performance become more important, and separately constructed UI and databases make more sense. When more users are involved they often have different requirements so decoupling the UI from the DB schema makes it more efficient to develop.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note on Java "projects that implement this idea" - [tynamo](http://tynamo.org/) is the new version of Trails framework

Answer (score 0):

There are many systems that build an interface for you to edit stuff directly from table information. End-user interfaces, however, must be tweaked a little bit. You may not want to reveal to the user every field in your table.

Frameworks that make good use of the MVC design pattern can let you do all kinds of things with your **models**, which are the preferred way to build new systems (rather than creating database tables directly).

To answer your questions specifically:

1. [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) allows you to construct forms (and a complete admin CMS) out of models.
2. It *is* a common thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Naked Objects](http://www.nakedobjects.org) is about one step removed from this.  They base the UI on an object model, and then persist the object model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting to consider the user in your design process if you are thinking like that. Bad mistake. Users don't like it when the interface changes, they would especially not like it if it changed frequently as they then wouldn't know what to do. Further, if you generate your UI on the fly based on the database structure, then what order would the objects be in?  UIs need to have objects in an order that makes sense to the users not the database designers.

Further in a well-designed database there are fields that are not meant for the users to see. Things like numeric keys, insert date, last updated etc.  You don't want to automatically expose these to the users and you certainly don't want them to have the ability to mess with the data in such fields.

Finally, if you don't think about the functionality of the page, then you aren't doing your job. A UI needs to be more than just a list of fileds that can be edited. You need to have constraints on who can see what, checks of the data before inserting to the database, business rules that need to be applied. You can't just autogenerate a lot of this (and you shouldn't even if you could!). Design needs thought and care.

Now as to drop down lists, of course you can generate them from the database and not the code, in fact it is the better choice. Just make the query the source for your particular object, not a list generated in code.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with the help of this cool tool from a developer in Philippines, it is called [COBALT](http://cobalt.jvroig.com/co/). You can download it [here](http://cobalt.jvroig.com/co/download/).